# VBA - How to delete all 20 rows after one specific value is found on a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that is filled with 20 rows of useless information all over the table on a random interval. It's the exact same 20 rows repeated over and over, so it always start with the same cell value. Like this:
https://i.gyazo.com/fdec2c2f6c6244d108e6bd07ad6e5181.png

I need to remove the entire row in which they appear, so i've been using this VBA code:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
'Updateby20140314
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim DeleteRng As Range
Dim DeleteStr As String
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)
For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRng = rng
        Else
            Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

But it's not quite useful since I have to do that 20 times for each file. So, i would like to know if there's a way to delete all the 20 following rows after the first row with useless information (the yellow on the image). I tried to do this by adding this after the "next" on the code above:

```
Set DeleteRng = DeleteRng.Resize(DeleteRng.Rows.Count + 20)
```

but didn't work (Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error).

I've hundreds of other files with the same issue, so a code that could do that really would save me a bunch of time.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Solved by arcadeprecinct below:

> Do the Resize before (or during) adding it to DeleteRng.
>   `Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng.Resize(20,1))`

Comment: `but didn't work` Can you give more details on what didn't work? Was there any error?

Comment: Do the `Resize` before (or during) adding it to `DeleteRng`. `Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng.Resize(20,1))`

Comment: I would use range.find and delete entire rows if you know the text you want to remove.  If the delete entire rows isn't working then debug it with simpler test cases

Comment: @Mrig the error shown was this one:  
Run-time error '1004'  
Applcation-defined or object-defined error  
When i debugged, it highlighted the sentence from above.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct That worked! Thanks a lot! :D